# Uploading to an API with Dropzone JS with data object

Tags: jquery, file-upload, multipartform-data, dropzone.js, form-data

Is it possible to use dropzone JS to upload to a remote server with an API and also include a data object in the request.

Here is an an exmaple of the request I need to send:

```
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="eventData" Content-Type: application/json {
    "Description" : "Some description",  
    "EventStoryIdsDelete" : [  ],  
    "PrivacySettings" : 4,  
    "Title" : "Photo event",  
    "EventStories" : [
    {      
        "Caption" : "Some caption",      
        "EventStoryType" : 2,     
        "TaggedUsers" : [      ],
        "Location" : {        
            "Latitude" : 51.52388,
            "Longitude" : -0.04333177,
            "FullAddress" : "Alderney Road, London, United Kingdom"
        }
    }
    ],
    "Date" : "2015-04-01T13:40:25.1790000"
}
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userﬁle"; ﬁlename="1.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
***image***
---------------------------acebdf13572468
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean you want to send your image with some custom param, right?
If true, you can use funtion sending of dropzone

example:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('div#uploadFile', { 
    url: "your_url", // Set the url
});
myDropzone.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData){
    formData.append('Description', 'Some description');
        ....
});
```

you can read about [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) here

Comment: And for sending multiple files in the same request I used `sendingmultiple`.